# Jailbreak iPhone 5 with 10.1.1

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, ios

Someone stole my phone today so I went and got a "new" older phone.  An iPhone 5.  It came with iOS 10.1.1 installed and I was wondering if there is a jailbreak for this?

I've been looking on Google and have tried a few different methods but they all seem to be fake and only install a "Cydia demo".

Can anyone point me towards finding a legitimate jailbreak or is non available?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I jailbreak?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336229/how-do-i-jailbreak)

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** You can now use [h3lix](https://h3lix.tihmstar.net/) by tihmstar to jailbreak 10.x on all 32 bit devices(computer required).

---

<s>At this time you cannot jailbreak the iPhone 5 on iOS 10.1.1.</s>

If you watched the video by EverythingApplePro, he said that the jailbreak currently doesn't work on iPhone 5(because it is a 32-bit only jailbreak). Right now, even if the jailbreak did work on iPhone 5, you won't be able to install anything YET.

Be on the watchout for a jailbreak for iPhone 5, but there are low chances of the iPhone 5 getting a jailbreak(on 10.1.1). I recommend the Youtube channels [iCrackUriDevice](https://www.youtube.com/user/iCrackUriDevice/videos) and [EverythingApplePro](https://www.youtube.com/user/EverythingApplePro/videos). It is recommended you stay on 10.1.1, because that has the most possibilities for a jailbreak.

Answer (score 0):

This is no "official" jailbreak on 10.1.1 yet. But there is a way to install Cydia onto iOS 10.1.1. Here is a video [by EverythingApplePro](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9Dgv2NW99Ic). According to him, right now the "jailbreak tool" only installs Cydia but you can't install any tweaks yet. So there is no point doing this. He said hopefully the full jailbreak will be put soon.

Comment: @books453 yep, the chances aren't high, even 9.3.3 jailbreak aren't for the iPhone 5.